# wait for nested promises to end with multiple requests on innermost

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

On the outmost *for* loop iterates over an array, this array is more specifically a list of objects where each contains an array with codes that i need to use in order to reach some information provided by an external API (For the sake of simplicity i am using mockup objects):

> data = [ {resultOfRequest, [code1,code2,code3] } ,  {resultOfRequest, 
>   [code4,code5,code6]  }, ... }

I need to traverse the data array, making one request per codeX and storing the result on resultOfRequest.

on a sequential paradigm it would be something like this:

```
for all items in data as work: 
     for all items in work as codeArray:
            for all codes in codeArray as code:
                   work.result = request(to-api, code) //waiting here for termination
```

I started with javascript a couple of days, and i've read it's meant to be non-blocking, but for this specific task i have to make it **synchronous** and wait until all objects have been inspected.

My attempt involves promises and looks like this:

```
//here the map iterates over the data array
// work = {resultOfRequest, [code1,code2,code3] }

  Promise.all(data.map((work, index) => {
             orclass.elserec(work, 0).then((results) => {
                    console.log(results);
             });
  }))
  .then(results => {
      console.log("finished")
  });
```

And as i need to end the recursive calls when it hits the index 3, i must do this at the callback:

```
 // here i try to iterate through the codeX arrays, and making requests 
//(where work =  {resultOfRequest,  [code1, code2, code3]})

  elserec: function(work, i){

    return request('api-url-code= work.array[i]', function(error, response, body) {
        result = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(body));
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200 && i !== 3) {
            console.log(result);
            work.resultOfRequest.push(result);
            return orclass.elserec(work, i+1);
        } else {            
            return result;
        }
    });
  }
```

It gets stuck at the 3rd request of the data[0] .

I would prefer to use only callbacks for this one, just to get a grip of how they work as i never used javascript , would rather prefer to use what came before promises first, to learn (**In this more specific context, callbacks in a simple asynchronous context are not anything special** i know)!

Comment: callback: `function foo(bar) { /* do stuff */; bar() }`.  Is not rocket science

Comment: Not in it's simplest form, i mean in this specific context. I know the basics of callbacks, and i used promises and chained promises with sucess.

Comment: `wait for nested loops to end synchronously` you can't, if the code has any asynchrony - did you mean sequentially?

Comment: You're probably right. But what i need is, to wait for all the requests, before i get to the end of the javascript and return the info to the client.

Comment: Your `elserec` is not a promise, but your trying to use it like one -> `elserec(work, 0).then`

Comment: There's some strange stuff in your code making it hard to understand what you're doing. 1: `result` is not declared anywhere. This makes it a global, which can cause issues with async code. Also you're calling `then()` on the result of `orclass.elserec()`, but it doesn't return a promise. This should be causing an error.

Comment: i got it all messed up while removing unnecessary code, i'm sorry! 
And a return was missing. It's not yielding any errors on the nodejs end.

Comment: i added some notes to the bits of code to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way of making this work.

recursive calls wasn't a great idea, so instead i mapped a function (with the request promise) to the array with codes ([code1, code2,code3]) and i end up with [elrec(code1),elrec(code2),elrec(code3)] . Afterwards i call promise.all with the promises on the array. it works:

```
Promise.all(data.map((works, index) => {
    return Promise.all(works.map((work, index) => {
             var promises = work.scopus.map(function(obj){
                return orclass.elrec(work,obj).then(function(results){
                   console.log("working!!!!!!");
                })
              })
             return Promise.all(promises);
    }))
})).then(function(){ //all api calls are done, proceed here})
```

the elrec function:

```
elrec: function(work, code) {
    return request('https://api.*****' + code + '*****',
        function(error, response, body) {

            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                result = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(body));
                work.elsev.push(result);
            } else if (response.statusCode == 404) {
                work.elsev.push("failed req");
            }
        });
}
```

As i wanted, i can wait for all promises to be "fulfilled" (All API requests are done, for all codes) and take an action after that.